# Issues with custom queries in views

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

I have defined this custom query in drupal 6  views

```
  function purchase_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
    global $user;
    if($view->name == 'user_accounts') {
      $view->build_info['query'] = "SELECT DISTINCT(content_type_account.field_account_number_value) AS my_account_numbers, content_type_account.nid AS my_account_nids FROM content_type_account INNER JOIN content_field_account ON content_field_account.field_account_nid = content_type_account.nid  INNER JOIN content_type_user_account_map ON content_field_account.nid = content_type_user_account_map.nid WHERE content_type_user_account_map.field_user_uid = $user->uid";
    }
  }
```

The query gives results when I run it in mysql console. But in the views itself it doesn't. Why is it so? Do I need to explicitly add the fields selected in the query as well somewhere?

[image]

[image]

Am I missing something?

I have attached the screenshots showing the two results. You can see in the views it doesn't show me the fields

Answer (score 1):

Is the user the same user that is issuing the query when it runs on the browser as the user your using to run the query with?

This could be a rights issue, maybe the view, or the tables the view is using is not granted to the user who is using it when it runs as web.